# Ubuntu 11.04 - when running OpenGL in window makes it choppy

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, opengl

I'm doing something with Ogre3D, but as i see when i run it in Window mode it's choppy, but with high fps( cca 150 ). When i run it in fullscreen mode everything works fine. I saw this behaviour only in Ubuntu. I've moved back to Ubuntu few days ago.

How can be this fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried disabling Compiz? (is that the right spelling? haven't used ubuntu for a long time)

Here is how you do it.

1. Press `ALT` + `F2`
2. Type this command: `gconftool-2 --type=string --set \
   /desktop/gnome/applications/window_manager/current /usr/bin/metacity`
3. When you are done, type this command: `compiz --replace`

Comment: Yes, it's because of compiz. But lines above won't work.

Comment: my information is probably out-of-date.